# How to add new vector that includes 0 and cumsum to dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

I want to add a new vector to a dataframe based on cumsum of previous column but starting from 0.

I've tried to create a vector with 0 and then the cumsum function but I have an additional row now from this. I've tried to remove the additional row but cannot.

```
mydata$time<-c(0,cumsum(mydata$duration))
```

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, time, value = c(0, 5, 9, 15.4,  : 
  replacement has 1138 rows, data has 1137

Comment: when you add 0, it is adding one more element

Comment: `c(0,cumsum(mydata$duration[-nrow(mydata)]))` will **not** include the last column value.

Comment: Thanks @akrun but I've tried to remove the additional element but I'm interrupting the cumsum argument when I do this.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas, apologies I must have put in every -nrow arrangement but that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to remove the last element and then do the cumulative sum, otherwise, it would have a mismatch between the number of rows of the original column and the new `vector` created

```
cumsum(c(0, mydata$duration[-nrow(mydata)]))
```